# Undefined offset error when iterating array after removing elements from it

Tags: php, arrays

I receive the following error message:

> Undefined offset: 1

It points to this block of code:

```
    $nbrProgrammingsRemoved = 0;
    for($i = 0; $i<count($this->products); $i++){
       if((($this->products[$i])->id)==$id){
          array_splice($this->products, $i, 1);
          for($j = 0; $j<count($this->programming); $j++){
     /*ERROR LINE*/ if((($this->programming[$j]->out_prod_id)==$id) || (($this->programming[$j]->in_prod_id)==$id)){
                $nbrProgrammingsRemoved++;
                array_splice($this->programming, $j, 1);
             }
          }
          return true;
       }
    }
    return false;
```

Specifically, the error points to the innermost if-statement. (The one with "||" in it).

Now, important to note is that this error does **not** always occur. It only ever happens **after** the following code has been run:

```
foreach ($this->programming as $key => &$prog) {
   if($prog->in_prod_id == $in_prod_id){
      if($prog->in_index == $in_index){
         unset($this->programming[$key]);
      }
   }
}
```

The purpose of this code is to iterate through my objects in my array and remove those associated with a certain ID. This does appear to work since the output on my website is as expected. It's only when I, after doing this, attempt to execute the first code-block that my error occurs.

I've tried troubleshooting this for a while now, but without success. Any ideas? Any more information that you need me to post?

Edit: For further clarification, if needed, the 1st code block iterates through an array to remove a single element of a specified ID. The 2nd code block iterates through another array and removes several elements.

Comment: change like :- `if(isset($this->programming[$j]) && ((($this->programming[$j]->out_prod_id)==$id) || (($this->programming[$j]->in_prod_id)==$id))){`  take care of brackets

Comment: @Anant Thanks! This was one way to solve it, as it made the loop bypass the missing index issue my element removal caused, as described by ConstantineUA in his answer below!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand, you have an array with indexes comming in a sequence:

```
$programming = array(
    0 => ...,
    1 => ...,
    2 => ...,
);
```

At some point you unset one element, so you array looks like this:

```
$programming = array(
    0 => ...,
    2 => ...,
);
```

And then you're using a for loop to iterate over all numbers from 0 up to N-1 (0, 1, 2, 3, 4 ... to be precise) presuming that all indexes are filled.

I think the best solution is to use a foreach loop in this case as it will care about indexes automatically and bypass deleted items.

Comment: This was indeed the problem, which I verified by examining my array properties. I can manage to bypass this using either foreach or using a isset check as described by Anant. However, may I ask you an additional bonus question? Would there be a way to "re-index" the array in question, so that this issue is completely eliminated altogether?

Comment: @AdrianHansson After removal do like `$foo = array_values($foo);`

Comment: @Anant And thank you! This resolved all of my questions!